# In an Android application can a 'ListActivity' be the main activity? i.e. can a 'ListActivity' start when I open an app?

Tags: android, listactivity

In an Android application can a 'ListActivity' be the main activity?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use a `ListActivity` as the main activity for your app. Just define it as the main activity in you `AndroidManfest.xml` file and it will launch when you open your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make listview as main activity

Go to androidmanifest.xml and edit

```
<activity android:name="**.ListViewTest**"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```